# Why is this timestamp off by an hour?

Tags: mysql

When I run this:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, FROM_UNIXTIME(0), NOW())
```

It gives me `1433183554` which is `2015-06-01 11:32:34`. But `SELECT NOW()` is `2015-06-01 10:33:17`.

How is it off by an hour?

N.B. `select unix_timestamp()` yields the correct timestamp.

Comment: basic rule of thumb with timestamps: if your results are off by some multiple of full hours, then it's almost always a timezone error.

Comment: But `NOW()` returns the correct time and `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, UTC_TIMESTAMP(), NOW());` gives the correct offset.

Comment: [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

Comment: @axiac Doesn't explain it. `FROM_UNIXTIME(0)` and `NOW()` return timestamps in the same timezone, do they not? And `TIMESTAMPDIFF` should respect DST changes, no?

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME()` and `NOW()` return `DATETIME` values, not timestamps (a timestamp is a number of seconds, it doesn't depend on timezones). [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) subtracts the dates it receives as arguments and it looks like it doesn't care about timezones and DST.

Comment: You can easily check this using the query `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2015-03-08 01:00:00', '2015-03-08 04:00:00');` (replace `2015-03-08` with the correct day when the `DST` started in your timezone, if I missed it). It should return `2` (because when `DST` starts an hour is skipped) but it returns `3`.

Comment: @axiac I was referring to the MySQL "timestamp" date type, not a unix timestamp. Doesn't that mean `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is bugged then?

Answer (score 1):

Per [axiac's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579682/why-is-this-timestamp-off-by-an-hour?noredirect=1#comment49230369_30579682), `TIMESTAMPDIFF` ignores timezones. You can verify this by running

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2015-03-08 01:00:00', '2015-03-08 04:00:00');
```

Which should give `2` (if you're in pacific time anyway) because we "spring forward" an hour, but instead gives `3`.

Comment: The purpose of the function is to quickly compute how many **whole** time units (its first argument) are between two dates (it returns an integer). I guess the knowledge and computation effort needed to take `DST` into account is a waste of time because the returned value cannot be exact (except when the unit is `SECOND`).

Comment: That's unfortunate. I expected it to give the actual amount of time that had passed. If you want the credit for this answer you can repost it and I'll accept yours.