# How to convert a DATETIME to unix timestamp (and handle negative dates correctly)?

Tags: mysql

Up until now I've been using this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dt2ts (d DATETIME)
RETURNS BIGINT deterministic
RETURN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, FROM_UNIXTIME(0), d);
```

But as I [just discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30579682/65387) this gives incorrect results if your date does not have the same offset as 1970-01-01, i.e. it's incorrect if your date is in daylight savings time.

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` doesn't work because it can't handle dates prior to the unix epoch.

So how can I get the *correct* unix timestamp for any given datetime?

Comment: Have you already looked at [this article](http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/mysql-from-unixtime.php#negavtiveEpoch)?

Comment: @PM77-1 You mean the article that suggests the same broken method in my question?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dt2ts (d DATETIME)
RETURNS BIGINT deterministic
RETURN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '1970-01-01', convert_tz(d,@@session.time_zone,'UTC'));
```

You need to [import timezones](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) in order for this to work. I don't think there's a way to do this without.